# How can I embed child data with many-to-many relationships?

Tags: javascript, miragejs

I have two Models in MirageJs:

- blog
- tag

Each blog could have more tags and vice versa. I made a many-to-many relationship with a join table called `blog_tag`. My problem is, when I get the response from the server, the **tags** only contains the id properties. How could I embed the whole tag object into the response?

```json
Response:
{
  "blogs": [
    {
      "title": "Some title",
      "author": "Author 0",
      "id": "1",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "1"
          // Other properties are not included here :(
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I like to see something like this:
{
  "blogs": [
    {
      "title": "Some title",
      "author": "Author 0",
      "id": "1",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Tag 0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My server config:
[Mirage REPL](https://miragejs.com/repl/v2/bf44f66f46)

```js
import { belongsTo, createServer, Factory, hasMany, Model, RestSerializer } from "miragejs"

export default createServer({
  serializers: {
    blog: RestSerializer.extend({
      include: ['tags'],
      embed: true
    })
  },

  models: {
    blog: Model.extend({
      tags: hasMany('blog_tag')
    }),

    tag: Model.extend({
      blogs: hasMany('blog_tag')
    }),

    blog_tag: Model.extend({
      blog: belongsTo(),
      tag: belongsTo()
    })
  },

  factories: {
    blog: Factory.extend({
      author(i) {
        return 'Author ' + i
      },
      title() {
        return 'Some title'
      }
    }),
    tag: Factory.extend({
      name(i) {
        return 'Tag ' + i
      }
    })
  },

  seeds(server) {
    server.createList('blog', 2)
    server.createList('tag', 10)

    server.create('blog_tag', { blogId: 1, tagId: 1 })
  },

  routes() {
    this.namespace = "api"

    this.get("/blogs", (schema) => {
      return schema.blogs.all()
    })
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the `blog_tag` model to be able to do many-to-many, Mirage.js will manage with just the `blog` and `tag` models.

See a working example here : [Mirage REPL](https://miragejs.com/repl/v2/9bd06c92ce)